# Using functions in R to copy the same file from multible folders and renaming the file based on folder structure

Tags: r, function, loops, copy, rename

I am new to R, and have built a working series of loops that copies and renames a single file from multible subfolders.

Great it works!! ... but what is this question about then?

Well, I have learned enough of R to know that most users agree that one should avoid loops and use functions instead whenever possible. This is because functions are a lot faster than loops.

When I apply my loop to my real data, it will have to cycle through +10000 files, and I would therefore like to make it as fast as possible.

Can my loop be expressed by using functions instead?
Alternatively can the loop be optimized in some way?
Any examples or suggestions on how to achieve any of the above will be much appreciated.

Info on my file-structure:

```
F:/Study
  1000
     1001
       Gait1
         annotations.txt
       Gait2
         annotations.txt
     1002
       Gait1
         annotations.txt
       Gait2
         annotations.txt
  59000
     59003 
       Gait1
         annotations.txt
       Gait2
         annotations.txt
```

*nb. the "Gait" folders contain many other files and directories, but I am only interested in the "annotations.txt" files.*

My loop:

```
for( a in seq(1000, 99000, by = 1000) ) {
  if (!dir.exists(paste0("F:/Study/", a))) {
    next()
    }
  for ( b in seq(1, 200, by = 1) ) {
      if (!dir.exists(paste0("F:/Study/", a,"/", a+b))) {
    next()
      }
    for ( c in seq(1, 2, by = 1)) {
        if (!dir.exists(paste0("F:/Study/", a,"/", a+b, "/", "Gait", c))) {
           next()
             }
      file.copy(from = paste0("F:/Study/", a,"/", a+b, "/", "Gait", c,"/annotations.txt"), to = "F:/Study/Annotations", overwrite = TRUE)
      setwd("F:/Study/Annotations")
      file.rename( from = "annotations.txt", to = paste0(a+b, "_Gait", c, "_annotations.txt") )
    }
  }
}
```

Result is files in my Annotations folder called:

```
1001_Gait1_annotations
1001_Gait2_annotations
1002_Gait1_annotations
1002_Gait2_annotations
59003_Gait1_annotations
59003_Gait2_annotations
```

tl;dr Can the loop be expressed using functions? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try the following (I have assumed that your /Annotations directory already exists). Does that work for you?

```
#get all file names (full path) with the pattern "annotations" within all folders in directory
files <- list.files("F:/Study/", full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE, pattern = "annotations")

#extract the desired parts for the new filename with regex
#d+ stands for 1+x digits, .* for anything and $ for the end of line
#extract only the second capturing group (the parts within parenthesis) via \\2
filenames_new <- gsub("(.*/)(\\d+/Gait\\d+.*$)", "\\2", files)
filenames_new <- gsub("/", "_", filenames_new)

#create the new filepaths
files_new <- paste0("F:/Study/Annotations/", filenames_new) 

#perform copy
file.copy(from = files, to = files_new)
```

Comment: There is a small typo in "filenames_new <- gsub("/", "_", filename_new)" - There should be an s in filename_new right?  
When that is done I get this error: 
cannot create file 'F:/Study//1000/1001/Gait1/Annotations/1001_Gait1_annotations.txt', reason 'No such file or directory'  
I am guessing it is because of double / after study

Comment: Ahh.... Now I understand what your code is doing. I was attempting to have the new files end up in the same folder "F:/Study/Annotations/". It works perfect If I change the line under #create new filepaths to:   files_new <- paste0("F:/Study/Annotations/", filenames_new)

Thank you! I have edited your answer and accepted it.

Comment: i am glad it works. sorry for the typo and thanks for correcting it.